# Android : Unable to instantiate application "packageName" : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, package-name, android-application-class

I am getting error related to the Unable to instantiate application "package name" and my Application class name is correct and annotation is also correct, even in Manifest file android:name is also correct and application Id also same as package name but still getting error. I think it's related to hilt and latest version issue.

**I am using Hilt(2.44.2) and latest version of Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Beta 1 and kotlin version 1.9.0**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.addpay.newsapp, PID: 17398
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.addpay.newsapp.NewsApplication package com.addpay.newsapp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.news.newsapp.NewsApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~8FyZg2bW9Pn1FIqmAuQXTQ==/com.addpay.newsapp-y51BQW4axBf-jgJjlzrzig==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~8FyZg2bW9Pn1FIqmAuQXTQ==/com.addpay.newsapp-y51BQW4axBf-jgJjlzrzig==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
```

Error

[image: Error]

app gradle

[image]

project gradle

[image]

libs.versions

[image]

manifest file

[image]

application file

[image]

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77574995/didnt-find-class-hilt-application-on-path-dexpathlist or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67650422/hilt-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-kotlin20test-hilt